# Solr is not going to configure

Tags: apache, search, solr, drupal-7

In drupal 7, website I am using search API, and trying to index data, getting error
An error occurred while trying to retrieve additional information from the Solr server: "500" Status: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /admin/stats.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /admin/stats.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437) at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)

Answer (score 0):

Granted I am using ApacheSolr rather than Search API, but I think this issue may not be Drupal module dependent. I had this problem locally when trying to use either Solr 3.5.0 or Solr 3.6.2 on my mac. When I switched to using [Solr 4.9.1](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.9.1/) this issue went away. I downloaded Solr 4.9.1, and placed it outside the root of my drupal install. I then copied the files from 
[my-site]/sites/all/modules/contrib/apachesolr/solr-conf/solr-4.x to [wherever you put the solr download]/solr-4.9.1/example/solr/collection1/conf (the file structure for the conf files looks different for solr 4 and solr 3). Then start solr as usual - from within solr-4.9.1/example run `java -jar java.jar`